# cat only prints one file descriptor

Tags: cat, file-descriptor

I am trying to understand how file descriptors work.

How come script2.sh below does not output the content of b.txt ?

```
$ cat a.txt
Hello
$ cat b.txt
World

$ cat script1.sh 
cat a.txt b.txt
$ ./script1.sh 
Hello
World

$ cat script2.sh 
exec 19<a.txt
exec 20<b.txt
cat <&19 <&20
$ ./script2.sh 
World
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<&19` means "replace stdin with FD 19" and `<&20` means "replace stdin with FD 20". These clobber each other. If you want to read two FDs, then do `cat /dev/fd/19 /dev/fd/20` instead.